Connecting Power BI Desktop to Postgres DB in AWS
I am trying to connect Power BI Desktop to Postgres DB in AWS RDS, the DB is in private network in AWS and not exposed to public, we connect to the db from jump host server in AWS console, so to connect from local we do ssh tunneling to jumphost from local and then connecting to the db from localhost with redirected port which I created in the ssh tunneling (for example localhost:13306), I have installed the AWS RDS Certificates in local machine.
Note: I am able to connect the db from PgAdmin using the same localhost server but not from the Power BI Desktop.
I have followed two different ways

Directly connecting to Postgres DB using localhost:13306 server



Using ODBC, I have tried with ODBC as well still its failing with below error, the password is incorrect. I was able test connection in ODBC and the connection test is successful but in the Power BI its giving password error.


